# clang & gcc interpret series of cast differently

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following:

```
#include <iostream>

int& addone(int& r) {
    return ++r;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << addone((int&)(int&&)7) << std::endl;
}
```

compiles, runs and prints 8, using clang, even with -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic .
Using gcc however, it does not compile at all, not even with -fpermissive .

Which is correct here? (preferably with quote)

clang result [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87e5229a3f5ce4f2), gcc result [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d82e8860e8040ec1)

Comment: Note that both compilers may be "correct". There's plenty of UB situations where the compiler is not required to print a diagnostic.

Comment: What is "the obvious thing" that it does? I don't see anything obvious that should happen when trying to increment a literal

Comment: golden rule is: if in doubt, gcc is correct. I have found clang to be very permissive over the years. I never release software compiled with clang without testing it on gcc first.

Comment: @Mat: It prints 8. A literal, captured as a rvalue reference, needs to become a temporary object, does it not?

Comment: @sp2danny you should [edit] your question to include the expected behavior, the observed behavior and the error messages.

Comment: @sp2danny I don't have the will to search the standard so I won't post it as an answer, but here are my two cents: no, it does not need to become a temporary object. A reference to a literal is just that: a reference to a literal. And even if you somehow would obtain a temporary, a temporary of integral type is not modifiable.

Comment: @RichardHodges I've seen plenty examples to the contrary. Even when MSVC was the only correct one. So the rule is: if one of the compilers disagree on godbolt, when there is definitely a bug. Either with your code (more likely) or with some of the compilers.

Comment: I agree with @bolov, this smells UB so strongly I don't feel the will to check the standard. You're modifying a temporary of a built-in type through evil casts.

Comment: There is a reason why [clang disallowes `(int&)7`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9b929fe91bebfc3), gcc is just smarter and recognize this evil cast through `(int&)(int&&)7`.

Comment: @sp2danny I suggest you create a bug report for clang.

Comment: As `std::cout << addone(static_cast<int&>(static_cast<int&&>(7))) << std::endl;` doesn't work, this means that you are asking nasty stuff from the compiler (namely the `int&` cast is a `reinterpret_cast` and not a `static_cast`). You shouldn't ask a language lawyer question with C-style casts (IMHO).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher _namely the int& cast is a reinterpret_cast and not a static_cast_ I'd say it is `static_cast` followed by `const_cast`.

Comment: replacing the c-style casts with `const_cast<int&>(static_cast<const int&>(7))` it works on both compilers

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the first conversion is OK. You convert an integer literal - a prvalue - to an rvalue reference. This causes temporary materialization conversion:

> [conv.rval] A prvalue of type T can be converted to an xvalue of type T.
> This conversion initializes a temporary object ([class.temporary]) of type T from the prvalue by evaluating the prvalue with the temporary object as its result object, and **produces an xvalue** denoting the temporary object.

Let us consider the conversion to lvalue reference:

> [dcl.init.ref] A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
> - is an lvalue (does not apply, the expression is not an lvalue)
> - has a class type (does not apply, the type is int&&)
>
> Otherwise, if the reference **is an lvalue reference** to a type that is **not const-qualified** or is volatile-qualified, the program is **ill-formed**. (applies)

It appears that the program is ill-formed. Lack of diagnostic from clang suggests a compiler bug.

Comment: the class type segment is referring to *conversions* where T1 and T2 are not reference-related.

Comment: the relevant segment is: *Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference*

Comment: however, does all this apply to casts?

Comment: @sp2danny I'm not sure anymore. There may be some rule missing, or I've just looked up wrong section.

Comment: I found regarding casts: (8.5.1.9) *The inverse of any standard conversion sequence (Clause 7) **not containing an lvalue-to-rvalue** (7.1), ..., can be performed explicitly using static_cast*